# ShareThis JavaScript alters IE9 history

Tags: javascript, social-media, sharethis

I am finding that in IE9 even for a simple act like clicking a link to navigate from one site page to another ShareThis is inserting as many as 7 entries into the history in between the referring page and the linked page.

[image: screenshot of history]

And looking on [their forum site](http://forums.sharethis.com/search.php?q=back%20button) I see lots of staff acknowledgements of this kind of issue but no solutions.

We link directly to [their current script](http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js) so it's not an issue of having outdated scripts on our server.

Aside from ditching them does anyone have any recommendations or experience with this issue?

**Update:** finally found a thread about this.  Not that ShareThis made any response but they have pushed new, flawed code probably yesterday...

http://forums.sharethis.com/topic.php?id=78328

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in newly pushed code from ShareThis.  They have resolved.  Anyone still seeing issues should do a hard refresh (Ctrl F5) or clear cache.

http://forums.sharethis.com/topic.php?id=78328